# How can I identify an unknown floppy format?

Tags: filesystems, floppy

I'd like to know if there are any programs available to get me the name of the filesystem used on a floppy, instead of just asking me if I want to format the disk.

I wish to exchange files with an old drummachine, an **E-mu SP-1200** ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mu_SP-1200), [vintage synth explorer](http://www.vintagesynth.com/emu/sp1200.php)). I must identify the filesystem used, so that I can look for specifications.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Well, I wish to create this filesystem so that I can exchange files with an old drummachine. But before that can be done I must identify the filesystem used, so that I can look for specifications.

Comment: if you give the name of the drummachine, maybe someone will know more about the filesystem?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux:

```
  file -s /dev/fd0
```

The file command identifies file types, including file system images. So what do you think happens on a floppy disk device file?

This will even answer correctly if some wise guy copied an archive directly to a floppy as if it were a tape drive.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I use mac os so file is available here as well.

Comment: file -s /dev/fd0 is correct. file /dev/fd0 will simply return /dev/fd0: block special

Comment: /dev/fd0: data :(

Comment: @EdRandall: Oops whatever format you have wasn't in the magic database. Now you have a truly hard time. Strings may or may not help but this will require intelligence.